# Can a switch statement containing truthy values be written as an object literal lookup?

Tags: javascript, object, switch-statement

I have the following code displaying an image based on gamma values of the gyroscope. My first shot at it was to write a switch statement but having used object literals before I thought this could be a cleaner alternative. Is there any way to do this with the following code? Or any other cleaner solution?

```
switch (true) {
        case (gamma <= -28):
            view360.goToItem(0);
            break;
        case (gamma <= -24):
            view360.goToItem(1);
            break;
        case (gamma <= -20):
            view360.goToItem(2);
            break;
        case (gamma <= -16):
            view360.goToItem(3);
            break;
        case (gamma <= -12):
            view360.goToItem(4);
            break;
        case (gamma <= -8):
            view360.goToItem(5);
            break;
        case (gamma <= -4):
            view360.goToItem(6);
            break;
        case (gamma <= 0):
            view360.goToItem(7);
            break;
        case (gamma <= 4):
            view360.goToItem(8);
            break;
        case (gamma <= 8):
            view360.goToItem(9);
            break;
        case (gamma <= 12):
            view360.goToItem(10);
            break;
        case (gamma <= 16):
            view360.goToItem(11);
            break;
        case (gamma <= 20):
            view360.goToItem(12);
            break;
        case (gamma <= 24):
            view360.goToItem(13);
            break;
        default:
            view360.goToItem(13);
    }
```

Comment: Try replacing the entire switch statement with `view360.goToItem( Math.floor((gamma + 31) / 4) )`

Comment: You're definitely abusing `switch` syntax here. Those chained checks should be written as `if`/`else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indexes are a function of the gamma, so you should write it as a function that captures that relationship. It looks like the relationship is simply `(28 + gamma) / 4` with an additional check gamma is greater than 60. Since you are using inequalities to capture the in-between values, you need to divide by 31 and take the floor. This will allow both `3` and `4` to return `8` for example. So this should match your `switches`:

```
function getIndex(g) {
    return g > 60 ? 13 : Math.floor((31 + g) /  4)
}
view360.goToItem(getIndex(gamma))
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark_M  If 60 was 24 thus making all gamma values /4, how would this change?

Comment: @Mark_M not sure if OP can have <-31 as gamma value, but your function will return -3 if g=-40.

Answer (score 1):

Not in this case, because you're using `<=` rather than `=`. Your whole method here would be better expressed with `if` and `else` - `switch(true)` is not really a switch.

Here's a switch you could convert to an object literal:

```
switch ( val ) {
    case 'a': return 'hello';
    case 'b': return 'goodbye';
}
```

Could be:

```
return { a: 'hello', b: 'goodbye' }[ val ];
```

Because the result of your switch (the argument to `goToItem`) is sequential (0, 1, 2...) you could use an array for this.

```
var gammaValues = [ -28, -24, -20, -16 /* etc */ ];
var idx = gammaValues.findIndex( value => gamma <= value );
if ( index !== -1 ) view360.goToItem( idx );
```

Answer (score 0):

May be using map can help

```
const mapBreakpointToItem = {
    -28: 0,
    -24: 1,
    ...
};

Object.keys(mapBreakpointToItem).some((breakpoint) => {
    if (gamma <= breakpoint) {
        const item = mapBreakpointToItem[breakpoint];
        view360.goToItem(item);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Or you can use math Math.floor((gamma + 31) / 4 for mapping breakpoints and items, but if something is changed its easier to change map object.